# Adding text outside of actual table

Tags: tables, rotating

I'm using this code and desperately trying to add text at the outside left saying "actual" and one at the bottom center saying "predicted".

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{.4\textwidth}|p{.4\textwidth}|}
\hline&\\
True Positives (TPs): 70
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Positive
    \item predicted outcome: Positive
\end{itemize} 
& False Positives (FPs): 5 
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Negative
    \item predicted outcome: Positive
\end{itemize} \\
\hline&\\
False Negatives (FNs): 8
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Negative
    \item predicted outcome: Positive
\end{itemize}
&   True Negatives (TNs): 17
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Negative
    \item predicted outcome: Negative
\end{itemize} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Example of a confusion matrix}
    \label{tab:cm}
\end{table}
```

I was able to use `\multicolumn` for the bottom one but it stuck directly below the horizontal line which was just not looking good.

The output should look like this:
[image: cm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way with a `\savebox` and a `\rotatebox` just to follow you and not use multicolumn:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{John Doe}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\savebox\mybox{\hbox{\begin{tabular}{|p{.4\textwidth}|p{.4\textwidth}|}
\hline\\
True Positives (TPs): 70
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Positive
    \item predicted outcome: Positive
\end{itemize} 
& False Positives (FPs): 5 
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Negative
    \item predicted outcome: Positive
\end{itemize} \\
\hline\\
False Negatives (FNs): 8
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Negative
    \item predicted outcome: Positive
\end{itemize}
&   True Negatives (TNs): 17
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Negative
    \item predicted outcome: Negative
\end{itemize} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}}
\rotatebox{90}{actual}\hspace{10pt}\parbox{\wd\mybox}{\usebox{\mybox}}\\[10pt]
\hspace{20pt}{\parbox{\wd\mybox}{\centering predicted}}
    \caption{Example of a confusion matrix}
    \label{tab:cm}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output is the one of your photo (almost)

Comment: does not work if u replace `actual` with `Example of a confusion matrix`

Comment: Thank you very much, that works just fine if I change it to `\hline&` instead of the first and second `\hline`. Otherwise the table does not close on the right.

Answer (score 1):

A slight simplification of koleygr's solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{actual}\hspace{\baselineskip}%
\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{.4\textwidth}|p{.4\textwidth}|}
\hline
True Positives (TPs): 70
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Positive
    \item predicted outcome: Positive
\end{itemize} 
& False Positives (FPs): 5 
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Negative
    \item predicted outcome: Positive
\end{itemize} \\
\hline
False Negatives (FNs): 8
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Negative
    \item predicted outcome: Positive
\end{itemize}
&   True Negatives (TNs): 17
\begin{itemize}
    \item real outcome: Negative
    \item predicted outcome: Negative
\end{itemize} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\[10pt]
\hspace{2\baselineskip}predicted

    \caption{Example of a confusion matrix}
    \label{tab:cm}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the rotatebox needs to have a new line break if we replace `actual` with `Example of a confusion matrix`

Comment: @jsbibram - or a \parbox.

Comment: Thank you too! I tried this one and it also worked fine. I just gave the correct answer to koleygr because he posted it first.